# WPF Textbox Binding. VB.Net 2017

Tags: wpf

Scenario:
A structure is associated with an indexed random access file.

Data is loaded from the file in the constructor  at boot time , and the structure is automatically assigned the data values from the file, and the textboxes in the WPF window is automatically populated.
The structure is also updated if the user enter new values in a textbox. So far so good.

The problem arise when the user loads a different dataset from the file when the program is running. This happen in a Button Click event. The structure is updated, but this change is not reflected in the textboxes.

Can someone hopefully shed some light on this.

Pretty new to both WPF and VB.Net

```
Public Class MainWindow
Shared myStruct As aStruct
Public Structure aStruct
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public year As Integer
    Public Property YearP As Integer
        Get
            Return myStruct.year
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            myStruct.year = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public salary as Integer
    Public Property SalaryP As Integer
        Get
            Return myStruct.salary
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            myStruct.salary = value
        End Set
    End Property
   .......
   .......
 End Structure

Public Sub New()
    Me.New(".\indxfile.ptx", ".\datafile.dat")

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    'InitializeComponent() ' Moved

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub

Public Sub New(Optional _IndexFileName As String = "", Optional _DataFileName As String = "")

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    Me.DataContext = myStruct

    Dim Retval As Integer
    Retval = GetRecord(2018, DataFileName, Len(myStruct), myStruct, IndexFilename)
    If Retval <> 0 Then
        MsgBox("Error")
    End If

End Class

<TextBox x:Name="Year" Text = "{Binding YearP, Mode = TwoWay}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Set' properties need to invoke the PropertyChanged event so that the data binding updates.